# Android: Vertical alignment for multi line EditText (Text area)

Tags: android, android-edittext, vertical-alignment, multiline

I want to have 5 lines for the height of the text area. I am using the following code.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lines="5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />
```

The text area looks fine, but the problem is that the cursor is blinking in the middle of the text field. I want it to blink at first line, at the first character of the text field.

Comment: try to remove your gravity "center", might be the problem

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="top"`

Answer (score 103):

This is similar to CommonsWare answer but with a minor tweak: `android:gravity="top|start"`. Complete code example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="5"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
/>
```

Comment: Do not use `top|left` unless you know you can control all the languages in your app, there are a lot of right-to-left languages out there (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) Keep it localization-friendly

Comment: @MariusBudin Presumably, `top|start` would be the correct alternative?

Answer (score 19):

U can use this Edittext....This will help you.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/EditText02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:lines="5"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
android:gravity="top"
```

or

```
android:gravity="top|left"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02" android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:lines="5" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="top|left" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:minWidth="10.0dip"
    android:maxWidth="180dip" />
```

it will work

Answer (score 3):

Now a day use of gravity `start` is best choise:

```
android:gravity="start"
```

For EditText (textarea):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="5"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
/>
```

Comment: Can you shed some light on why this works? I would have expected `start` to have worked like `left` (for Western languages) - i.e., only affect the horizontal gravity, but it also seems to do the job of `top`, too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. We are mainly use this for support RTL. Like in Arabic language, it's go to Right, instead of Left. And It's also go to `top` that you already asked. In generally we start writing from Top-Left side, that's why this `START` also show same characteristics. @ban-geoengineering

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `layout:weight = 5` instead `android:lines = 5` because when you port your  app to smaller device - it does it nicely.. well, both attributes will accomplish your job..