# multiline edittext through android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android multi line editText (Text area)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446544/android-multi-line-edittext-text-area)

I would like to work with multi-line edit text so i extended the edit texts size to 250width and 150height,but the only problem is the cursor starts or blinks at the middle of the edit text,i need it to starts at the beginning of left side of the multi-line edit text,how to do this?

Comment: Before posting question on stack overflow please do some googling .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set that edit text gravity as top .

```
android:gravity="top"

<EditText 
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="top"/>
```