# EditText with multilines android API level 8

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a problem:
with this xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/nomenota"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/corponota"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
    <TableLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow >
        <Button android:id="@+id/visualizza_notaOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/notaOK"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/nota_annulla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nuovanotaannulla"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

My activity is showed like this:
[image]

As you can see, the body of my message in centered in a big edittext and i don't want this result.
The result that i want is like this link:[link of layout that i want to achieve](http://www.google.it/imgres?q=notepad%20android&hl=it&sa=X&biw=1280&bih=705&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=mEaGtT4AndO8IM:&imgrefurl=http://www.androidtapp.com/ak-notepad/&docid=Wedo4L2DuIs1DM&imgurl=http://cdn.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/ak-notepad-new-note.jpg&w=480&h=320&ei=hCqNT9vLOs3OswaPgZmXCQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=570&sig=102238338620115758561&page=1&tbnh=140&tbnw=210&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:66&tx=105&ty=90)

CAn someone helps me?
Thanks in advance.
Marco.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446544/android-multi-line-edittext-text-area

Comment: great Chirag!!! thanks for all because i have resolved with noting!! really thanks...

Comment: if you post like answer i accept your answer Chirag!!!

Comment: please if my question in good and it is not unclear or not offensive please rate my quesiotn...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply this property in edittext `android:gravity="top"`